# Angular net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, google-chrome, cors

Error in console:

> OPTIONS https://site/api/v1/oauth2/token
>   net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

My request:

```
$http({
    method: "POST",
    url: 'http://site/api/v1/oauth2/token',
    data: {grant_type: 'client_credentials'},
    headers: {'Accept':'application/json', 'Authorization':'Basic XXX', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
});
```

My php:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header("Cache-control: no-cache");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    return json_encode(array("status" => "success"));
    die;
}
```

It's a mobile app, created by AngularJS.
In mobile device everything is working.
In Chrome, Firefox, Microsoft Edge i see ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: Can you clarify by what you mean by "in chrome firefox etc" .. do you mean if you open that url in that browser?

Comment: AngularJS send OPTION Request in browser, i see it in console.

Same in Postman "Could not any response"